# php - How to have an output of a query as the input of another on postgresql?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'm quite new with php and databases. I want to get the query from the search and enter the information in the Order table. I used pg_copy_from() but it is not working.

```
$keyword = pg_escape_string($_POST['keyword']);

$result = pg_query($dbh, "SELECT i.items_id, i.name, o.price, o.store_id, o.status, o.time, o.is_cancelled, o.gifting_carts_id FROM items i, orders o WHERE o.item_id = i.item_id AND i.name = $keyword");

// Printing results in HTML
echo "<table>\n";
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "\t<tr>\n";
foreach ($line as $col_value) {
    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
  }
  echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";

// GET INFO FROM QUERY


$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (quantity, item_id, store_id) VALUES('$quantity', '$item_id', '$store_id') returning orders_id";
$result1 = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
if (!$result1) {
    die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
    header("Location: error.php");
}
header("Location: success.php");
```

Is this correct syntax:

```
 $line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)
 echo $line["i.item_id"] . " <- Item ID \n";                         
 $sql = "INSERT INTO orders (item_id) VALUES('$item_id') returning orders_id";
```

Comment: You should seriously consider using PDO, especially if you're new to this. Among other useful things, PDO lets you raise exceptions when there are errors, so you don't have to sprinkle `pg_result_status` everywhere in your code.

Answer (score 3):

### `pg_copy_from` doesn't do what you think

The `pg_copy_from` PHP function is designed for bulk inserting rows into the database using a CSV-like format, supplied as an array from PHP. You don't need it for what you're doing, and it won't work. Each of those lines is failing with an error, but you aren't checking for errors, so you're ignoring them. If you check the PostgreSQL log files you'll see the errors.

### Use the `pg_fetch_...` functions

Instead you want [`pg_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-array.php) (to get an array that's also indexed by name), [`pg_fetch_result`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-result.php) (to get an individual field) or [`pg_fetch_object`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-fetch-object.php) (to get it as a PHP object you can access with fields as column names).

### Check for and handle errors

Your code fails to check [`pg_result_status`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-status.php) after database calls. So it'll fail in unexpected and usually ugly ways if a database call fails.

You should check `pg_result_status` after each call. It should be `PGSQL_TUPLES_OK` for any `SELECT` or `... RETURNING` query, and `PGSQL_COMMAND_OK` for commands that don't return tuples. If it's anything else, you should use [`pg_result_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-result-error.php) and/or `pg_result_error_field` to get error details and act on it appropriately - usually logging it and reporting a generic error to the user if it's a public facing website.

### SQL Injection

Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Imagine what happens if someone sends the keyword:

```
`'); DROP TABLE items; --`
```

See http://bobby-tables.com and [the PHP manual on SQL injection](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). You should be using `pg_query_params` or PDO.

This is also likely to cause more mundane problems. For example, any text value with a single quote in it will fail to insert because it'll terminate the text field, making your SQL statement's syntax invalid.

Always use parameterized statements (often called "prepared statements" though they're actually subtly different).

### Transactions, concurrency

What if two copies of this code run at the same time? Will it do the right thing?

If there's an error half way through the program, will the database be in a sensible state?

When database programming you always need to think about these things. Transactions and locking are your main tools to make sure that the results are right. I won't discuss those in detail here, but I strongly recommend taking a look at the [PostgreSQL tutorial](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html) and documentation, which discusses them in detail.

### ANSI joins

Please, please, please write your queries with explicit `INNER JOIN`s. As you have bigger queries, this starts to become vital for readability. E.g.

```
SELECT
   i.items_id, 
   i.name, 
   o.price,
   o.store_id,
   o.status, 
   o.time, 
   o.is_cancelled,
   o.gifting_carts_id 
FROM items i
     INNER JOIN orders o ON (o.item_id = i.item_id)
WHERE i.name = $keyword"
```